# When is JavaScript content crawlable (if ever)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, web-crawler

I wish to implement a timeline feature on a website I am developing for a Twitter timeline. One option I have is crawlable and available directly under Twitter's settings under "widgets:

```
<a class="twitter-timeline"  href="https://twitter.com/hyttetomter" data-widget-id="289297710840954880">Tweets by @hyttetomter</a>
<script>!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document,"script","twitter-wjs");</script>
```

The code is firstly not valid script for XHTML so I looked for a plugin or script that was and found[this plugin that was and found a plugin called Tweet for jQuery](https://www.google.no/search?q=tweet%20plugin%20&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aofficial&client=firefox-a) as it's customizable for CSS, but is this crawler friendly?
What are the tecnicalities that seperate script that is crawlable from that which isn't? Should I just turn of JavaScript to see for myself? Is jQuery content ever crawl-able and what actions must (assuming there are) I take to make any of my own jQuery-generated content crawlable? I have found mixed references online regarding this so please direct me to a trustworthy resource if you feel it can assist me.

Comment: Check out [Google's guide on ajax crawling](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/) for some info on making your site crawler-friendly while having dynamic ajax content.

Answer (score 2):

Crawlers fetch HTML pages. That is their only functions. They get the name of your stylesheets and javascripts because they are part of your HTML document head (as link and script tags) but their purpose is neither to style the pages nor enhance the behaviour. They fetch HTML static information and parse in order to make assumptions about its content. If your content is being generated after a javascript trigger, then the crawlers are not going to get it.

One solution to make it crawler-friendly is to make a fallback for them. But this has to involve rendering your twitter information on the server-side. Facebook does this:

```
<noscript>
  <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; URL=/home.php?_fb_noscript=1" />
</noscript>
```

Facebook inserts this meta tag in its document header. It is only triggered for noscript cases (hence, crawlers), and refreshes the page with the given url, which in the facebook case means "render the wall on the server-side, dude doesn't have javascript". Of course, crawlers have to know how to proceed with this tag.